# Bug with Single Table Inheritance (STI) and has_and_belongs_to_many (HABTM) associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, single-table-inheritance

Using Rails 3.0.7, and have the following 4 models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Administrator < User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :administrators
  has_and_belongs_to_many :meetings
end

class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients

  def self.foo
    self.joins(:clients => :administrators)
  end
end
```

Calling:

```
Meeting.foo.to_sql
```

produces:

```
SELECT meetings.*
FROM meetings
INNER JOIN clients_meetings ON clients_meetings.event_id = meetings.id
INNER JOIN clients ON clients.id = clients_meetings.child_id
INNER JOIN clients_administrators ON clients_administrators.child_id = clients.id
INNER JOIN users ON users.type = 'Administrator'
```

but it appears as if the final join relationship between "clients_administrators" and "users" has been missed. I think the last line of SQL should read:

```
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = clients_administrators.user_id
WHERE users.type = 'Administrator'
```

Is this a bug? or have I misunderstood something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a [bug](http://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1396), but it has been resolved in Rails 3.1.